# Register User Creation Form using software

Tags: forms

I need some idea .I have to design a software that may be console application which should accept URL of Add user page (page dose not have captcha or anything like that).
what my application needs to do is fill that page form i.e username,password and email 
and USES POST to register that user

Is it possible?

is it possible for that application to cross platform compatible

what programming language should be used